# Invite someone to collaborate with admin rights in github

Tags: github

Following the GitHub doc: https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository I have succeed in adding a friend as a collaborator on a personal public repo. How can I grant him with full access so that he can set up the CI for instance?

Answer (score 1):

The collaborator, according to "[Permission levels for a user account repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/access-permissions-on-github)" should already have full access to your repository.

That list of permission might not iclude "setting up the CI instance" though.